# Recursive material name printing logic

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a function which goes through every name in an object. This object has an array parameter `materials` which holds other objects. Those objects have the same array parameter which hold more objects and so on.

My code lines 3-5 just repeat while adding `.material` and another variable. Also the code will only go into an object's name four layers down or else I have to keep repeating more code.

How can I cut down on this mess?

```
var itemList = function(x) {
    console.log(x.materials[0].name);
    for (var i = 1; i < x.materials.length; i++) {
    console.log(x.materials[i].name);
       if (x.materials[i].build !== "BasicFactory" && i !== 0) {
           for (var j = 1; j < x.materials[i].materials.length; j++) {
               console.log(x.materials[i].materials[j].name);
               if (x.materials[i].materials[j].build !== "BasicFactory" && j !== 0) {
                   for (var k = 1; k < x.materials[i].materials[j].materials.length; k++) {
                   console.log(x.materials[i].materials[j].materials[k].name);
                   if (x.materials[i].materials[j].materials[k].build !== "BasicFactory" && j !== 0) {
                       for (var l = 1; l < x.materials[i].materials[j].materials[k].materials.length; l++) {
                       console.log(x.materials[i].materials[j].materials[k].materials[l].name);
                    }
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You could call `itemList` recursively for each object in `x.materials`:

```
var itemList = function(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.materials.length; i++) {
        console.log(x.materials[i].name);
        if (x.materials[i].build !== "BasicFactory" && i !==0) {
            itemList(x.materials[i]);
        }
    }
};
```